# Copy document to another library as new version & preserving its existing version

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have two document libraries 'projects' and 'reviews' both the libraries have versioning enabled and Require documents to be checked out to 'yes'. Using SharePoint desinger 2010 workflow the document from projects is copied to reviews library and users continue to work on document present in project library.

At certain stage the document from Reviews needed to copy to Projects library. When the document is copied to project library only the active version of 'Reviews' library should be copied to projects library while mainting its previous versions of the orginial document in projects library.

Approaches I used: I tried using 'copy' activity in SharePoint designer workflow. I could just completely overwrite the file or completely create a new file.

I also tried using send to action, it failes with error 'Copying to the destination did not complete successfully'.

I dont want to give 'copy content & structure' option to user as it involves several clicks and higher permission to user.

Version: SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the exact same question but using SharePoint Online. In your case if you can make an HTTP Web service request then you can try: [Move a document with version history using a Nintex HTTP Get](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss-j-AoBtpw) . Don't get hung up because it is Nintex as ultimately it's a HTTP call and you can make that with a tool like Postman as well as SPD

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about how exactly to make an HTTP call in a SPD workflow to move documents with their history?